# I have a general solution as an affine map in matrix form. How can I tell if its surjective and/or injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

So for example, the general solution is (1,2,3)d + (4,5,6) = (a,b,c)

How could you tell if this is surjective and/or injective?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: well my thinking is it cant be surjective, because lets say a,b,c = (0,0,0) then there is no d such that a = 0, b = 0 and c = 0. And I think it is injective because you would be multiplying (1,2,3) and then adding (4,5,6) and i dont think any different d's would lead to the same a,b,c. So injective but not surjective.

Comment: What about $d=-2$? That equal $(0,0,0)$. You are right but choose a different point. Then all you have to do is prove the injective part. What happens if $f(d)$ and $f(D)$ give the same answer? Can you prove $d=D$?

Comment: Haha sorry, total mind blank. For injectivty, could you set up two equations such as (1,2,3) (1) + (4,5,6) = (1,2,3) (2) + (4,5,6)? You could then simplify the equation to 1 = 2 which isnt true so therefore, d != D so it is injective.

Comment: That doesn't work because you chose $1 \neq 2$ so you're just concluding what you assumed. Try doing the same thing but with $d$ and $D$ instead.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you very much! Sorry for being so slow.  (1,2,3) (d) + (4,5,6) = (1,2,3) (D) + (4,5,6) thus d = D.

Comment: You've set it up correctly, but you'll need to do a short calculation to prove it. It's almost trivial but it's necessary.